# How could I save webpack-dev-server changes?

Tags: javascript, webpack, save, bundle, webpack-dev-server

I'm using Xampp for my PHP developing.
Beside, I write codes in javascript in MVC architecture. When I run `"dev": "webpack --mode development"` in NPM, that's all ok and I see changes in bundle.js . But when I run `"start": "webpack-dev-server"` and I go to localhost:8080/js/bundle.js, I see changes, but in real, it is not saved. Because I go to my virtual host and there is no change!
How could I save changes exactly? Why is this happening?
This is my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ["babel-polyfill","./resources/assets/js/hadi/index.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.join( __dirname, 'public/js'),
        publicPath: '/js/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:{
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dev server of webpack is not meant to save anything, it is just a development server with live reloading, hot-modules and many other features.
When you run webpack command (like a build) it actually creates the output files, your javascript bundle and your static assets are copied to your dist folder, depending on your configuration.

The production bundle is much lighter in size so it can be deployed, and the dev server just stores a temporal bundle on memory while it is running.

Comment: So there is no way to save it? I should run ```npm run dev``` every time I update it?

Comment: According to your configuration yes, you should also check https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/ so you know how to configure your production build